# Why does wp_enqueue_script ignore my 'wp_head' hook?

Tags: hooks, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

I would like `css_head_scripts` and `js_head_scripts` to be appended to `wp-head`

but Wordpress completely ignores it? Am I missing something?

```
    function css_head_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'Master Stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri()."style.css" );
    }
    function js_head_scripts() {
        echo '<!--[if lt IE 9]>';
        wp_enqueue_script( "HTML5 Shiv", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js" );
        wp_enqueue_script( "Respond.js", "https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js" );
        echo '<![endif]-->';
    }
    function js_footer_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( "My jQuery", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" );
        wp_enqueue_script( "Bootstrap", get_template_directory_uri()."/js/bootstrap.min.js" );
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'css_head_scripts');
    add_action('wp_head', 'js_head_scripts');
    add_action('wp_footer', 'js_footer_scripts');
```

Comment: What have you done to debug? What other hooks have you tried? Do any of the scripts get enqueued, or none of them? Can we see the rendered output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You problem lies with how you are using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). It does not print out the `<script src=""></script>`, instead it adds it to a list of Javascript files to printed out at the appropriate time.

There is a different hook that is called for when you should add your Javascript and CSS: `wp_enqueue_scripts` (you use it for CSS too). Your `css_head_script()` is called too late as the function to print the scripts is called earlier in the `wp_head` hook.

As for the `js_head_scripts()`, this will just not as you expect regardless because `wp_enqueue_script()` does not print the script element. It just adds it the list of scripts to print out. The best you'll get is conditional tags with nothing inside them.

Regarding your `js_footer_scripts()`, you don't need an extra function for that because `wp_enqueue_script()` has a parameter for adding the script to the footer instead of the head.

```
function add_js_and_css() {
  global $wp_scripts;

  // CSS
  // The label should be safe for an ID, and you need the trailing slash
  wp_enqueue_style( 'master-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri()."/style.css" );

  // Javascript
  // By setting the fifth parameter to true, WP will print it in the footer
  wp_enqueue_script( "my-jquery", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js", array(), '1.10.2', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( "bootstrap", get_template_directory_uri()."/js/bootstrap.min.js", array('my-jquery'), '3', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_and_css' );

function add_conditional_js() {
  ?>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]
    <script src="<?php echo esc_attr('https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo esc_attr('https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js'); ?>"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <?php 

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_conditional_js' );
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Two things: (1) WordPress is adding jquery AFTER `bootstrap.min.js` is there a way to remedy this? (2) Is there somewhere online I can read about the `$wp_scripts` object? The [Class Reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/#Classes) is in poor repair.

Comment: You can use, the dependency parameter. It tells WordPress what scripts are needed before it. `wp_enqueue_script( "bootstrap", get_template_directory_uri()."/js/bootstrap.min.js", array( 'my-jquery' ), '3', true );`

Comment: I'm afraid there is no good source on the `$wp_scripts` object. In general, you never have to touch it.

Comment: Thanks Seamus. I noticed that `html5-shiv` and `respond.js` are being displayed in the HTML without being commented out w/IE conditionals? Am I missing something?

Comment: My bad, that only works for stylesheets. I'll update the answer regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead `wp_head` to enqueue scripts and styles.

Check if there's a [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) call in header.php

See codex for adding [conditional comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Styles#Conditional_Styles).

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works, I thought I'd add the up to date way on how this should be done.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_134784_enqueue_html5shiv_respond_bootstrap');
/**
 * Enqueue Theme Scripts and Styles
 *
 * @link https://gist.github.com/bryanwillis/7fd5356a9d18d0c7815f
 */
function wpse_134784_enqueue_html5shiv_respond_bootstrap()  {

    // Theme Stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'master-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // Local jQuery
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap',
        get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '3.3.6',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'html5shiv',
        'https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js',
        array('bootstrap'),
        false,
        false
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'respond',
        'https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js',
        array('bootstrap'),
        false,
        false
    );

    // Conditional comments
    wp_script_add_data( 'html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    wp_script_add_data( 'respond', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

}
```

If you want to use the jquery cdn you'd use this instead of the above local jquery although you might want to consider an [approach with a local fallback](https://github.com/roots/soil/blob/master/modules/jquery-cdn.php#L16).

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', false, false, true );
```

Comment: The `!is_admin()` check is totally unnecessary. `wp_enqueue_scripts` only runs front end. Back end scripts are enqueued with `admin_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: [That is correct](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/9fb5c540bb7888faec05670bd70a93e0593dcfb1/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L224). I used to never use that, but recently I've seen it being used [all over the place](https://github.com/roots/soil/blob/master/modules/jquery-cdn.php#L12), [#45440](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45440/43806), [#55930](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55930/43806) and assumed I had overlooked something. I'm guessing people saw examples using is_admin()  hooked into `init`, and just assumed it applied (or maybe it has changed over the years)...

Comment: Jip, I'm not pretty sure where this comes from, but `wp_head()` can only ever run on the front end, so anything hooked to it like `wp_enqueue_scripts` can only ever run on the front end. Checking for admin on anything hooked to `wp_head` is as irritating and useless as the `function_exists()` checks on core functions. You cannot deactivate core and still use your theme ;-)