# Javascript not included

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have tried to include my javascript file in the following way:

```
function theme_scripts()
{

    wp_enqueue_scripts( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu-fix.js',array('jQuery'), true);
}

add_action('init', 'theme_scripts');
```

This file is included in `functions.php`

But for some reason the script does not get included.

I have got `wp_head()` in `header.php` and `wp_footer()` in footer.php.

### Edit

So I changed my script to:

```
    function theme_scripts()
    {
    wp_enqueue_scripts( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu-fix.js',array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
    }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

But still it isn't loaded.

This is how my `footer.php` looks like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <?php wp_footer();?>
```

Comment: Try using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of `init`. See [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Notes) and [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55928/16121) for details. Also, your `wp_enqueue_scripts()` call is missing either the `$version` parameter, or has `$version` set to `true` and does not set the `$in_footer` parameter.

Comment: So I added some more information, in my post. But still no fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing up the [singular `wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), which adds a script, with the [plural `wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) which is an action and a function that triggers that action. I think you want

```
function theme_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu-fix.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

i.e. register against the enqueue_scripts-plural action that calls enqueue_script-singular.

Comment: This, and also remove that google jquery from your footer. WordPress has jquery included. You don't need a special version.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove this from footer.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And One tip: Use wp_enqueue_script to load all JS on your web page.

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies are case-sensitive - you need `array( 'jquery' )` (no uppercase Q).

Comment: Ok so I changed it. But still no menu-fix.js